# Django - user authentification error (django.contrib.auth)

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-authentication, django-users

Following [this tutorial](https://www.fir3net.com/Web-Development/Django/django.html) I have created a simple login page. But when I submit the login information, following exception in Python appears:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jirka/miniconda3/envs/molinf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/jirka/miniconda3/envs/molinf/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/jirka/molinf/02-database/moldb/views.py", line 100, in login
    login(user)
  File "/home/jirka/molinf/02-database/moldb/views.py", line 94, in login
    if request.POST:
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'POST'`

### Here is my code:

URL in `urls.py`:
`url(r'^login$', moldb.views.login, name='login')`

Login view in `views.py`:

```
def login(request):
    print(request, type(request))
    logout(request)

    if request.POST:
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None and user.is_active:
            login(user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

    return render(request, "login.html")
```

Login form in `login.html`:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="LoginForm" action="{% url 'login' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% if next %}
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
    {% endif %}
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="username">Username</label>
        <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="password">Password</label>
        <div class="controls">
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Login</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I have found that output from `print(request, type(request))` in `views.py` is following after submitting the form:

```
<WSGIRequest: POST '/login'> <class 'django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIRequest'>
hanicka <class 'django.contrib.auth.models.User'>
```

`hanicka` is the username of authenticated user (the username which I sent through the login form). **It is obvious that the exception comes from this, but how is this view executed twice and how is the `User` model getting here?!**

Comment: @jotik you've been doing a lot of edits,with the common feature of editing out "hell" from posts. While some of your edits are substantial and constructive, in some cases such as this one you've ignored obvious issues, and *only* removed "the hell". I can understand that you find this expression strong, but please consider that this is not considered rude by the vast majority of users, and superfluous edits like this are not beneficial for the community. This post with an accepted answer for more than 2 weeks has been bumped to the front page for no good reason. Please reconsider your actions.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Ok, thanks! I didn't know these get bumped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not familiar with Django and I'm missing some context, but just looking at your code, the example you followed and the Django docs, I am curious what would happen if you chose a different name of your `login` function to:

```
def login_user(request):
```

Just in case there are naming clashes...

Comment: Many thanks! It would have never occurred to me. Sometimes I should also follow the naming in tutorials :)

Comment: you can also change the django's `login` function name: `from django.contrib.auth import login as user_login`

Comment: @ahmed Yes, that is obvious now, but I would rather not change the import naming just for cleaness.